# ThreadPoolExecutor threads having contention with other threads

Tags: java, threadpool, executors

I am working on a enhancement for an existing Java application. The application is a message processor which processes several millions of messages daily. It basically written using Core Java with threads and queues are implemented using Collection classes.

In this application some type of the messages are running in a single thread. I was given the task to make this particular part of the application to multi threaded to process the messages faster, as we have dual processors.

Since we are using Java 5, I took the approach of using ThreadPoolExcecutor. I have created processor threads for each clients so that message for a particular threads can be processed in its own thread. The processor threads are implementing Callable interface as this will allow me to check the future object whether the previous task is finished or not.

During initialization process, I will go over all the clients and create processor threads for each and store it in map using their id as unique key. To track previously submitted job, I do keep the future object in another map again using same id as unique key.

Below are some snippet of code which I used : In main class -

```
ThreadPoolExecutor  threadPool = null;
int poolSize = 20;
int maxPoolSize = 50;
long keepAliveTime = 10;
final ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1000);
threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(poolSize, maxPoolSize,keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS, queue);

   ....
   ....
 for (each client...) {
   id = getId()..
   future = futuremap.get(id);
   if(!future.isDone())
      continue;
   if(future == null || future.isDone()) {
      processor = processormap.get(id);
      if(processor == null) {
         processor = new Processor(.....);
         //add to the map
         processormap.put(id,processor);
      }
      //submit the processor
      future = threadPool.submit(processor );
      futuremap.put(id,future);
 }
}
```

Processor Thread

```
public class MyProcessor implements Callable<String> {
        .....
        .....
    public String call() {
        ....
        ....
    }
 }
```

**The Issue**

The above implementation is working good in my test environment. However, in production environment (**Edit#1** - <strike>Ubuntu</strike>, Linux Slackware, Java - 1.6.0_18), we observed that other threads of the application which are not managed through this new ThreadpoolExecutor are getting affected. i.e., their tasks are getting delayed for hours. Is it because the threads created by ThreadPoolExecutors are taking the whole resources or whatsoever and not giving the chance to other threads.

The new threads created using ThreadPoolExceutor are doing independent task and are not in contention with other thread for resources. i.e., there is no race condition scenario.

In the log, for the new Threads, I can see that there are maximum of 20 threads running (corepoolsize) and there are no rejection exceptions, i.e., the number of submits are within the bounds of the queue.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you change the thread priorities (from the pool or other) anywhere in application? This can have different effects on different platform.

Comment: No. There are no priorities set explicitly for threads.

Comment: I am using Java 1.6.0_18 (64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0-b13, mixed mode). Server OS - Linux - 2.6.27.9.

Comment: Are the ThreadPool threads compute-bound? I.e. are they in tight loops with no external interaction and running for a long time?  You might need to call `Thread#yield()` occasionally if that is the case.

Comment: The processor thread basically connects to database and sends the messages to the clients. These processes as such do not take longer time. The issue is with the older threads which without my implementation works very fast. After I implemented ThreadPoolExecutor for a part of the application, other threads are getting delayed.

Comment: I would try running your code with the size of the threadpool set to be smaller.  Unless you have 20 cores, you are not going to gain from having that many worker threads, and it just might fix your issues.  Weird, interesting problem.

Comment: Have you run jstack to see what the state of the blocked / slow threads are?

Comment: It might be worth posting details of the processing you are assigning to the `Processor` created as, as Jim Garrison has hinted, if these are performing lots of computation then the other threads may be starved of processing cycles.

Comment: @andersoj - Actually I could not replicate the same issue in my test environment (Windows 7, JDK 1.6_018). I will do one more round of load test and keep it for a while, to see if it occurs in test environment and then probably use jstack to find the state of blocked/slow threads. Thank you.

Comment: @Paul - Actually the processor thread, reads messages from database and send it to the clients (writes to each ones socket connection). The whole thing takes around 300ms for each message.

Comment: @Philip - We have 8 cores with dual processors. I think your suggestion makes sense. But then, as for as I understand, each thread gets time slice to execute the process. Morever, If there is any issue with the time slicing for the threads, I should be easily be able to reproduce the situation in my local server (Windows 7, Single Processor) using say, just 10000 messages, rt?. But I am not able to reproduce it. Probably I will have to run it for whole day and check the performance.

Answer (score 0):

My prior experience with Linux threading showed clearly that it is much more prone to thread starvation when very busy than the same system running in Windows under the same load.  I wrote a test program that indicated that under heavy CPU load a few threads will get far more CPU time than the others when using the standard wait/notify primitives - IIRC, by an order of magnitude.  My solution was to use a reentrant lock in fair mode to round robin them.

Again, IIRC, throwing in `Thread.yield` at the conclusion of each work event had no positive effect.

All of this may be significantly impacted by which of the several threading libraries your Linux distro is using.

You may get some improvement by adding a throttler to the work queue which is dominating the work-load, though it would be best if that were somehow adaptive to the amount of work pending on the other unrelated threads.